# Getting the return value of a lambda function?

Tags: javascript

```
function user_id( sessionID )
{
    db
        .where({ session_id: battleData })
        .get('vp_sessions', unserialize);
}

function unserialize(err, results, fields)
{
    var serialized = results[0];
    return PHPUnserialize.unserialize(serialized.user_data);    
}
```

Is it possible to return the the return value of unserialize?

Comment: Not if it's asynchronous (and I believe it is).

Comment: See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446) Of course, you're not using Ajax, but you *are* using an asynchronous API, and the solution is identical. `user_id` cannot sychronously return a value that is acquired asychronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get the return value of a function when you call it. None of the code you have provided calls it.

You pass it to the `get` method which may call it, but it is up to the code of the `get` method to do something with the return value.

Comment: Ah, I feared as much. If that's the case I might have a bit of a problem in my hands :( Thanks for the reply.